# How to find the time difference between two events in groups

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

There is a data frame which contains the following information detector id, the channel id (each detector has some channels) and the timestamp (let it be an integer for simplicity) and a number of counts that occurred in a given (`detector_id`, `channel_id`) pair.

How to calculate the number of days passed since the last nonzero event in the given (`detector_id`, `channel_id`) pair?

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    "detector_id": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    "channel_id": [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    "counts": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
})
```

I tried to solve this in the following way:

```
df["diff"] = df["time"] - df.groupby(["detector_id", "channel_id"])['time'].diff()
```

It produces the following result:

```
   time  detector_id  channel_id  counts  diff  expected
0     1            0           1       0   NaN       NaN
1     2            0           1       1   1.0       NaN
2     3            0           1       0   2.0       1.0
3     4            0           0       1   NaN       NaN
4     5            0           1       0   3.0       3.0
5     6            0           1       1   5.0       4.0
6     7            1           1       0   NaN       NaN
```

As you can see the given solution doesn't take into account `counts` column. We should set a difference to zero once we see `counts > 0` and propagate otherwise.

Comment: Row 5, `expected` should be `NaN` since `counts` is 1 there, right?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler, I think it should be 4, as the last nonzero observation was 4 days ago

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be close, but needs testing on your full data:

```
def f(subdf):      
    ffilled = (subdf.loc[subdf['counts'] > 0, 'time']
               .reindex_like(subdf)
               .ffill()
               .shift())
    return subdf['time'] - ffilled

df['diff'] = (df.groupby(['detector_id', 'channel_id'])
                .apply(f)
                .sort_index(level=-1)
                .values)

   time  detector_id  channel_id  counts  diff  expected
0     1            0           1       0   NaN       NaN
1     2            0           1       1   NaN       NaN
2     3            0           1       0   1.0       1.0
3     4            0           0       1   NaN       NaN
4     5            0           1       0   3.0       3.0
5     6            0           1       1   4.0       4.0
6     7            1           1       0   NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it looks really close to what I searching for, but there is still a problem with the first entries. For the first row (index 0) expected value is `NaN` as there are no previous measurements, the same holds for the row at index 3 (the combination `detector_id=0,channel_id=0` occurs for the first time, therefore distance to the previous positive response from this detector is not defined.

Comment: @CommonSense I understand now, thank you - edited my answer.

Comment: Now, it works like charm for this dataset. Can I ask you to provide some comments with the explanations? For example, why do you `sort_index`?

Can I generalize it for the case when `counts` is an arbitrary integer (not only zero and one) by doing `subdf['counts'] > 0`?

Comment: Once again thank you, I mark your solution as the correct one. I will upvote it later when I have enough points.

Comment: @jezrael good catch, `.loc` is more pandas-idiomatic and provides the same result in this case. Edited, thank you!

Comment: @CommonSense, yes, the `== 1` can (and probably should) change to `> 0`, which I have just edited. The `sort_index(level=-1)` is a bit of a hack, needed because the `groupby.apply` returns rows that are not always in the same order as in the input data, even with `groupby(..., sort=False)`. The `groupby.apply` returns these unsorted index labels as the innermost (`level=-1`) index level. Sorting by this level ensures that the `values` align with the input data. There's probably a better way to do this, but I couldn't think of one!